# How to overcome undefined error in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. You can also find it at [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nE72g/).

```
<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return arith()">
      <center><table>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1>Value 1 </font></td><td><input type = "text" id = "num1"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1>Value 2 </font></td><td><input type = "text" id = "num2"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Addition" id="check1"/>Addition</td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Subtraction" id="check2"/>Subtraction</td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Multiplication" id="check3"/>Multiplication</td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Division" id="check4"/>Division</td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1><input type = "submit" value = "Submit"></font></td></tr>
        </table></center>
 </form>
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
        var op;
        function changeCheckBox(val) {
            try {
                var i;
                var max = document.myform.check.length;
                var count = 0;
                op = val;

                for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                    if (document.myform.check[i].checked === true) {
                        count++;
                        serNoChecked = i;
                    }
                }
                if (count === 1) {
                    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                        if (document.myform.check[i].checked === false) {
                            document.myform.check[i].disabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (count === 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                        document.myform.check[i].disabled = false;
                    }
                }

                if (null === max) return false;
                if (count === 0) {
                    return true;
                } else if (count > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }

        function arith() {
            var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value, 10);
            var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value, 10);
             var newVal1;
             var newVal2;
             var newVal3;
             var newVal4;

            if (op == "Addition") {
                newVal1 = n1 + n2;
            } else if (op == "Subtraction") {
                newVal2 = n1 - n2;
            } else if (op == "Multiplication") {
                newVal3 = n1 * n2;
            } else if (op == "Division") {
                newVal4 = n1 / n2;
            }

            var demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
            {
                var html = "";
                html += "Addition =" + newVal1 + "<br/>";
                html += "Subtraction =" + newVal2 + "<br/>";
                html += "Multiplication =" + newVal3 + "<br/>";
                html += "Division =" + newVal4 + "<br/>";
                demoP.innerHTML = html;
            }
            return false;
        }
 </script>
```

While running it, I am getting undefined error for all the four operations.
If the user enters the two values and if they click all the checkboxes, it should display all the outputs corresponding to the arithmetic operations. How to do that?

Comment: Code is there...http://jsfiddle.net/nE72g/

Comment: Again, I don't see any code here..

Comment: This site expects you to share your code here and not on other websites

Comment: While answering, you peoples are giving in jsfiddle only know...thats why I make a question from there

Comment: If someone answers with nothing more than a link to jsfiddle, then it is a bad answer and should be deleted.

Comment: Check my answers, I always contribute the code along with the JS Fiddle demo, show me one answer without code... Why we emphasize on sharing code? Because if tomorrow the link is dead, your question won't be useful for future visitors

Comment: And anyways, some good person edited your question, we won't be doing this job for you everytime so start sharing codes, voting for reopen

Comment: This is a rather large pile of code. What is the exact error message you get? What part of the code triggers it? What are the values of the variables involved at the time?

Comment: @Quentin, true, I failed to see the `var` statement. I'll go get my eyes checked.

Comment: You're not calling `changeCheckBox` anywhere in your code thus, the `op` is never set.

Comment: To all who voted for putting this question on hold: could have just given a person a bit more time to improve the question before doing so.

Comment: @DineshKumar As a follow-up to my previous comment: maybe you meant to have `onchange="changeCheckBox(this.value);"` for every check box? With this change, your code seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `changeCheckBox` anywhere in your code thus, the `op` is never set. Maybe you meant to have `onchange="changeCheckBox(this.value);"` for every check box (with this change, your code seems to be working as expected)?

```
<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return arith()">
    <center><table>
        <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1>Value 1 </font></td><td><input type = "text" id = "num1"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1>Value 2 </font></td><td><input type = "text" id = "num2"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Addition" id="check1" onchange="changeCheckBox(this.value);" />Addition</td></tr>
        <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Subtraction" id="check2" onchange="changeCheckBox(this.value);" />Subtraction</td></tr>
        <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Multiplication" id="check3" onchange="changeCheckBox(this.value);" />Multiplication</td></tr>
        <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Division" id="check4" onchange="changeCheckBox(this.value);" />Division</td></tr>
        <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1></font></td><td><font face="verdana,arial" size=-1><input type = "submit" value = "Submit"></font></td></tr>
    </table></center>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you volpav. now I found the problem. But it is not displaying the four outputs. Anyone output is displayed..how to resolve it?

Comment: @DineshKumar Not sure what you mean by "Anyone output is displayed...". Tested locally and it displays the four lines beneath the form: "Addition = undefined Substraction = 5 ...". Don't forget to include `<p id="demo"></p>` along with the code I've provided.